# type arguments [org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector] do not conform to method product's type parameter bounds [T <: Product]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, word2vec

I need output `Dataset[Vector]`, but below code has thrown error.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("Hello world!")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    //blah blah and read data etc. 
    val word2vec = new Word2Vec()
        .setInputCol("value").setOutputCol("vectors")
        .setVectorSize(5).setMinCount(0).setWindowSize(5)
    val dataset = spark.createDataset(data)

    val model = word2vec.fit(dataset)


    implicit val vectorEncoder: Encoder[Vector] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.product[Vector]
    val result = model.transform(dataset).select("vectors")

    val output = result.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.getDouble(1)))
}
```

Error is thrown as soon as start the program:

```
type arguments [org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector] do not conform to method product's type parameter bounds [T <: Product]
    implicit val vectorEncoder: Encoder[Vector] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.product[Vector]
```

Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector` is a seled trait and not a case class (case classes extend `Product`). You can't use `Encoders.product`.

Comment: Try `implicit val vectorEncoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Vector] = org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder[Vector]`.